# When I select between two dates in SQL Server, the result is returned from in range and out range together?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query

```
select * 
from Vw_storeout 
where ItemDate between '14/10/2018' and '15/10/2018'
```

The result gets data from September and October. Actually just I want data from October.

I've changed date format to `varchar(50)`.

Comment: Why do you use the varchar type for `ItemDate`? Please consider using something like the date type. If you want to keep varchar, the answer would be something like `where ItemDate like '%/10/2018'`. But i would not recommend this.

Comment: "I've changed date format to varchar(50)." There's your problem right there. Store dates as date, or DateTime2 if you also need the time. Do not store them as strings, ints, or whatever else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date is date, you should compare it as date not string.

```
select * 
from Vw_storeout 
where TRY_CAST(ItemDate AS DATE) between CAST('20181014' AS DATE) 
                                     and CAST('20181015' AS DATE);
```

You should store `ItemDate` as `DATE` instead of `VARCHAR(50)`.

Comment: I've got this error.
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @jacobdavid Sure, added date literals as `ISO 8601` which is culture independent.